# 301 redirect в .htaccess

Tags: редирект, .htaccess, mod_rewrite

Ребята, помогите, всю голову уже сломал:

Необходимо, чтобы при переходе по адресу

```
http://localhost/subdmn/m/catalog/good/1/
```

происходил редирект на

```
http://localhost/subdmn/m/catalog/good/1
```

а этот url в свою очередь показывал то, что находится по адресу

```
http://localhost/subdmn/m/catalog/good.php?id=1
```

Я сделал так (файл лежит в `C:/site/subdmn/m/catalog`):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^good/([0-9]+)/$ good/$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^good/([0-9]+)$ good.php?id=$1 [L]
```

При переходе по ссылке `http://localhost/subdmn/m/catalog/good/1` всё открывается нормально, но, когда я запрашиваю `http://localhost/subdmn/m/catalog/good/1/`, сервер переадресовывает меня на адрес `http://localhost/C:/site/subdmn/m/catalog/good/1` , что, естественно, ничего хорошего не дает.

Заметил, что, если оставить файл .htaccess пустым, первая ссылка даёт 404, а вторая всё так же частично заменяется локальным путём. НО! если удалить htaccess, обе ссылки выдают 404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот этого не хватает:

```
RewriteBase /subdmn/m/catalog
```

> Директива RewriteBase устанавливает базовый URL для преобразований в контексте каталога. Директива RewriteBase используется в конфигурационных файлах каталогов .htaccess. Это будет работать локально, т.е., префикс локального каталога отбрасывается на этом этапе обработки и ваши правила преобразований работают только в оставшейся части. В конце он автоматически добавляется обратно к пути.

Comment: благодарю!